# I target all links using a.forEach((item) ...is it possible to include 'or class x' when needing to target non-anchors?

Tags: javascript, html

This script is on a custom Javascript cursor. It works as intended, however I want the mouse to react the same way when it hovers over an single element (img) that is not an `a` - which is what the script currently targets.

Is there a way I can adapt the script to essentially look for *'target anchors or an element with a class of .link'* (for example). Or would I need to duplicate the block of code and use `getElementsByClassName`? Maybe I'd be better off using something like my `data-` to target elements rather than all `a` elements?

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown", function () {
  cursor.classList.add("cursor--click");
});

document.addEventListener("mouseup", function () {
  cursor.classList.remove("cursor--click");
});

a.forEach((item) => {
 item.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    cursorTrail.classList.add("cursor-trail--hover");
 });
 item.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
   cursorTrail.classList.remove("cursor-trail--hover");
 });
});

a.forEach((item) => {
 const interaction = item.dataset.interaction;

 item.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
   cursor.classList.add(interaction);
 });
 item.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
   cursor.classList.remove(interaction);
 });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select elements using an arbitrary CSS-selector by using `document.querySelectorAll`

In your case, you would do something like this:

```
let links = document.querySelectorAll('a, .link');
links.forEach((item) => {
   ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks that's a big help. Might be a simple question (I dunno) but just trying to understand what I'm doing more and if it's right/there's a better way!